# Flash sms class 0 nokia

Tags: sms, message, at-command, nokia, flash-message

I searched a lot of things about the Flash sms class 0, and I'm really interested in the AT+command to send flash sms to any number.
But I read that this command can be used only on specefic devices, like some versions of Nokia.
Also, some people did this on a basic Terminal on OS X with a 3G+ key.

Please can someone explain me which phone do I need to execute the AT commands, or what 3G+ key do I need ?
I didn't find a real tutorial on how to do that...
For example if I buy an old Nokia phone, is it OK for sending the AT commands ?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a programming forum. Please read [**`How To Ask`**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show the code you've tried & point where you think the problem is. Also tag with your programming language. Questions about software opinions / recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

https://adywicaksono.wordpress.com/2008/02/08/how-to-send-flash-sms/

You don't have to get a Nokia phone..
I use a gsm modem - [https://www.amazon.com/Generic-Wavecom-Q2303A-Interface-Commands/dp/B00BD0V57I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BD0V57I)
You can connect to it via sample telnet and run any (supported) AT command. Way simpler...

And I have no idea what do you mean by key 3G+ :/